# Delete punctuation marks and return a meaningful sentence - Python

Tags: python

I am using the following code to delete punctuation marks from a sentence:

```
   import string
   translator = str.maketrans({key: None for key in string.punctuation})

   s = "I am,a boy"
   print(s.translate(translator))
```

But when for example, s = "I am,a boy", the output is "I ama boy", I want the output to be " I am a boy" (with space b/n "am" & "a"). But if originally there was a space,as in s= "I am, a boy", I want the output to be "I am a boy" i.e. just delete the punctuation mark.

Comment: Why don't you replace punctuation with a space then replace double spaces with a single space?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: thanks for the comment, but what if s="I am , boy" then the output will have triple spaces. Any idea how I can eliminate those double and triple spaces?

Comment: Brute force way: `while " " " " in s: s = s.replace(" "  " ", " ")`  (stupid SO keeps collapsing my whitespace)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this is to replace all punctuation with a space, then just replace all runs of whitespace with single spaces by splitting and re-joining the string. (Although an Tadhg points out, this also replaces line breaks.)

```
import string
translator = str.maketrans({key: " " for key in string.punctuation})

s = "I am,a boy"

print(" ".join(s.translate(translator).split()))
```

The job can also be done with a regular expression:

```
import re, string
# need to escape a couple of characters to build a valid regex
regex = " *[%s]+ *" % string.punctuation.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("]", "\\]")

s = "I am,a boy"
print(re.sub(regex, " ", s))
```

Now, this regex doesn't address punctuation found at the beginning or end of the string, where it will be turned into a single space. The easiest way to handle this is probably to do:

```
print(re.sub(regex, " ", s).strip())
```

Comment: A lot simpler then what I was going to post, although it does change `\n` into spaces.